# AngularJS $http setting headers

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-http

I'm trying to set http in AngularJS, but it seems I'm doing something wrong.

```
app.controller("mainCtrl", function ($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method: 'GET',
        url: '***',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        }
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("data", data);
        console.log("status", status);
        console.log("headers", headers);
        console.log("config", config);
    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("data", data);
        console.log("status", status);
        console.log("headers", headers);
        console.log("config", config);
    })
})
```

My main interest is to set `accept: json`, but if I check the request headers in Google Chrome's dev tools it always just says `Accept:\*/\*`.

EDIT:
CORS is set on the server and I'm still getting this error no response.

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://inpro.smid.co.cz:8080/InproRestApi/webresources/entities.regions. Request header field Access-Control-Allow-Origin is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers in preflight response.
```

Answer (score 1):

It could be a CORS issue did you check if the server has configured the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header.

Comment: It doesn't. I will see when it will be implemented then. thanks

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is set to *

Comment: Hi Jan, I just checked your server(the one in your error message). The error it provides indicates that this is a server-side issue. I think the access control header is not set to * as you assume. I have checked your snippet and it works fine (on another server) you can check this yourself using https://httpbin.org/

Comment: Hi, thanks for a help Niels. We used to have it there, now we started playing with its settings and it disappeared again.

Answer (score 0):

Simplify Add as below in your controller class

**@CrossOrigin(origins = "*")**
public class Controller {

Comment: while code only answers might answer the question in this instance, it is better to include `WHY` your answer fixes the OP's issue so they can learn from the experience